# Passing parameters with jQuery's AJAX implementation

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the code below for example.

```
var loadUrl = 'test.php';

var dataObject = { category_id: category_id, grade_val: grade };

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: loadUrl,
    data: dataObject,
    dataType: 'html',
    error: ajaxError,
    success: function(response) {
        callback(response);
    }
});
```

Now I'm wondering if I have a var called `category_id` in JavaScript, is it ok to use it like the above? ...or will this end up with the value of `category_id` being used as the name of the `_POST` variable being passed to PHP? Can I surround the names of the variables with single quotes to avoid this such as:

```
var loadUrl = 'test.php';

var dataObject = { 'category_id': category_id, 'grade_val': grade };

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: loadUrl,
    data: dataObject,
    dataType: 'html',
    error: ajaxError,
    success: function(response) {
        callback(response);
    }
});
```

...or should I just rename my JavaScript variables?

Comment: Should be perfectly alright..  Key values are always used the way they are sent ... `Value names` are replaced with the corresponding values at the time of execution

Comment: Your original code is just fine, and the modified code will work exactly the same.

Comment: Shouldn't your `dataType:` be JSON instead of HTML?

Comment: @gibberish reason being?

Comment: @gibberish the `dataType` relates to the _response_, not the _request_.

Comment: @Brett the reason being he's talking gibberish...

Comment: @Brett NB: if all your `success` function does is call `callback`, just write `success: callback`.  Better yet, learn about the deferred APIs (.e.g. `.done`) - once you start using them you'll never to back to `success` et al.

Comment: Will check all that out, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to use any legal identifier as the "key" in an object literal.  The browser will not attempt to evaluate that identifier and replace it with its value.

Using the quotes is optional.